# Can you listen to azure service bus using AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, azureservicebus, serverless, azure-servicebus-queues

Per [link](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/events/servicebus/)! here, Azure Functions Service Bus trigger lets you listen on Azure Service Bus. We are currently using mostly AWS for our cloud services. And we are working with vendor who has real time notifications using Azure service bus. I would like to know if there is anyway to connect to service bus using lambda. Anytime there is a new message on the bus, we would like our AWS lambda to invoke and take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. However you can use Azure functions (Azure serverless offering) triggered by Azure Service bus to consume the messages.

If you really want cross vendor trigger then you need to consume azure service bus message, convert the message into http payload and trigger AWS lambda with Http payload that has message contents.

Comment: Hi Imran - Can you pl. clarify your second comment? Will below work? I build AWS lambda that executes every minute. It then pings the Azure service bus for new messages. If there are messages, it will queue them to my SQS and next lambdas can invoke

Comment: I think that's too many hops. Consume the message using azure function from Service bus. In the your azure function convert the message into Http post request and then call your lambda with payload as http post. In short your lambda is http triggered which can accept post requests with parameters. and your azure function will call your lambda after consuming the message and recreating the contents that are passed to lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudwatch Event Rule: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html

You specify your event source -- a supported Service and an action/API call and the targets and setting up the required IAM setting(Lambda permission etc. if you create from IaC tools like terraform..) And you are good to go!

Then as long as Cloudwatch event rule is up, all the events that falls into the rule you specify will trigger your lambda.

Event rule can also be used a "cron schedule" for lambda, which I have been using. I did encounter some delay very rarely tho.

Update: to make it as real time as possible, you would need to make modification to your vendor's Azure account to enable some message pushing to your AWS endpoint(an API gateway), which I assume is a NO. Other than that, a AWS self contained solution is to set up a cloudwatch event rule to pull your vendor's Azure HTTP endpoint every 1 minutes and store the stuff in your own SQS queues.

Comment: I want to consume azure service bus message in real time as much as possible. Per your suggestion, is it possible for me to have cloudwatch event rule that triggers lambda every minute. I then read azure service bus message and if there are messages, I then queue them to SQS and build further lambdas for further processing

Comment: Updated the anwser. Yes cloudwatch event rule at a 1 minute rate is totally possible but at the same time, it is not close to real time. As the I mentioned in the answer, if modifications in your vendor's Azure account is allowed, there are other things you can do. e.g., you set up an API getway in your AWS account, let vendor account's event bus push events(using Azure's services) to hit your API gateway. And a lambda will sit behind the API gateway to do whatever.

Comment: If you are not worried about a large chuck of messages to be fetched per minute then Cloudwatch rule that triggers a lambda is sufficient. You may create multiple Azure SB clients in a single lambda call to fetch even a larger set. In my case, I have a controller lambda that checks for the number of messages in the queue, it then invokes a number of lambda functions dynamically where each lambda runs 50 clients asynchronously to fetch 100 messages per client. So 1 lambda invoke can easily digest 5000 messages. But there is no out of the box solution for listening the messages from AWS.